# why TextView can't maintain width?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm learning android and trying to make an android text editing app,
I'm trying to make a numbers column at the left to display the number of the row I'm at,

so I made a `TextView` and listened to every change in the `EditText` then got the `EditText.getlineCount` and drew the numbers from 1 to lineCount in the `TextView` every time the text changed.

it works well but, 
after 13 lines of text when the keyboard disappears there is an extra space appears in the text view, then when I start typing it disappears, and then reappears again when the keyboard disappears.

[(With the extra space when not typing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plpp4.png) (i highlighted the extra space in green using MS paint)
[(without extra space when typing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rQ0Q.png) (the numbers stick to the edge of the screen)
here is a [video](https://youtu.be/HiiZsn7NFJo) if you still have no clue what I am talking about.

could someone tell me what is happening?

here is my code

java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText;
TextView showLnNum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    showLnNum = findViewById(R.id.showLineNumber);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(editTextListener);
}

TextWatcher editTextListener = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        showLnNum.setText("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= editText.getLineCount(); i++) 
        showLnNum.append(i + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.algohinys.texteditor.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top|start"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/showLineNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textSize="16" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theLineBetween"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:hint=" "
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="16"
        tools:text="edit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you expect it to look like and what it currently does?

I have no idea what `when the keyboard disappears there is an extra space appears in the text view when I start typing it disappears and then reappears again when the keyboard disappears.` means, can you be more specific?

Comment: Agreed, it'd be cool if you could point out what the erroneous behavior looks like.

Comment: I  put pictures and a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting a fixed width multiplied by the logarithm of `LineCount`.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
            int lineCount = editText.getLineCount();
            double digits = Math.log10(lineCount) +1;
            double digitsFloor = Math.floor(digits);
            double size = digitsFloor *20;
            showLnNum.setWidth((int) size);
            showLnNum.setText("");
            for (int i = 1; i <= editText.getLineCount(); i++)showLnNum.append(i + "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `"android:maxlines="99"` (or something large like that) on your TextView widget?

Comment: Not working, the problem is with the width so maybe the problem is in the method LineNumberDrawer or some other attribute in the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

i don't find anything as extra space created. could you please try trim() while setting the text to the view.

Comment: Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to set a fixed padding and margin for the `textview` and the `EditText`

```
  android:padding="1dp"
  android:layout_margin="1dp"
```

Comment: @7odafarghal it's really strange, but I think there's a workaround here, but not a real solution. you can set a fixed width like `20dp` and a padding of `3dp` and the problem would go, but the downside is when the number reaches 3 or more characters, in that case you can solve it by always checking the characters length and when it's more than two then increase the textview's width and so on.